# imread returns null when loading certain images using opencv java

Tags: java, opencv, imread

I have been loading images with opencv in java using this code:

```
   Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

But I ran into trouble when Mat returns null when loading a certain kind of image and I've been having a hard time figuring out why.

Here are the specs of the image that works fine when loaded:

Size in pixels: 771 × 465 pixels 
Print size: 271.99 × 164.04 millimeters 
Resolution: 72 × 72 ppi 
Color space: RGB color
File type: JPEG image 
details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk4to.jpg

And here is the image that returns null when loaded:

Size in pixels: 1684 × 2784 pixels 
Print size: 213.87 × 353.57 millimeters 
Resolution: 200 × 200 ppi 
Color space: RGB color 
File type: JPEG image 
details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JPLy.jpg

I can't see any obvious differences except their resolutions and I haven't read anywhere that resolutions interfere with the readability when using imread on opencv. Are there limitations as to what image properties are needed before it can be read when using imread?

Comment: Could you post the images so we can try them out?

Comment: @DforTye works fine:  https://imgur.com/c0SNNft does not work fine: https://imgur.com/9pNcZoc

Comment: I was able to read both images: `Size images 771x465 1684x2784`. What version of `opencv` are you using?

Comment: `area images 358515.0 4688256.0` another test

Comment: @DforTye OpenCV 3.4.1

Comment: I am using `3.2.0`. Could you please add the full exception?

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be > 0`

Comment: @DforTye I tried to syso the image and here is what i got `Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1cc3219b670, dataAddr=0x0 ]`

Comment: The majority of the cases the problem is that the filename is wrong, it could be worth it to double check the name and make sure all the characters that need to be escaped are escaped. OpenCV returns null in this function whenever it cannot read or decode the image. Make also sure the image has read permissions.

Comment: the filename has alphanumeric characters only so i guess i can cross it out of the possibilities being the source of the problem. how do i check the permissions of the image? @api55

Comment: not sure what is your OS, normally this problem occurs more in linux/Mac, you can go in a terminal to that folder and write `ls -l`. You should see something like `-rw-r--r--  1 api55 users` first part is the permissions, then I think is the user id and the file owner and the group. This example has 3 r, that means that the owner the group and everyone else can read it. In Windows I am not sure how to check this...

Comment: i used the absolute path of the image and it fixed the problem! thanks for your help  @api55